# Names based on real world culture

Tags: culture, worldbuilding-resources, names

I'm trying to name the gods of the pantheon of my world with names inspired by real world cultures and civilizations. My concern is that I come up with names that aren't culturally insensitive; particularly towards middle eastern and native american cultures. Are there any resources that I can consult?

Comment: Have you tried googling names to see if they happen to be offensive?

Comment: Beware that quite often gods have names which are *specific* to the gods, and never used for mortals. No Greek woman in the Antiquity would be called Athena, or Hera, or Artemis. Roman goddesses had personal names, such as Minerva or Venus, whereas Roman women did not -- they used feminine forms of their father's clan or family name. Our One True God has a Jewish name; Muslims never mention His name, but rather always referred to Him as God, of The Merciful, The All-Powerful etc. Some cultures prefer to use foreign names; e.g., many European cultures tend to use Hebrew, Greek or Slavic names.

Comment: You might actually find [this](https://azgaar.github.io/Fantasy-Map-Generator/) useful?

Comment: https://www.samcodes.co.uk/project/markov-namegen/ - try a procedural name generator

Answer (score 2):

Each language has a unique phonology (the sounds that correspond to letters) either in their Latin script or in the romanized form of their language. Look up the Latin script phonology of the language and try to come up with a name that fits the phonology. Don't use the names of real gods/goddesses (as that will essentially guarantee an offensive name). This should work.

Comment: I usually do this (pick a language with a suitable phonology) and then combine existing names from that language. Like, if I were going for Amharic, a city name would be Adsuba (Addis Abbeba + Aksum)

Answer (score 1):

If your looking for deities in the context of mythologies, [ https://pantheon.org/ ] 
might be useful.

If your looking for a list of deities from a bunch of different cultures with short descriptions, Encyclopedia of Gods might be useful [[https://www.amazon.com/Encyclopedia-Gods-Over-Deities-World/dp/0816029091]](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0816029091).